# how to get response in json format

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch videos from student id and subject id . here i want to fetch only 3 columns from database with json format

Below is my code can anyone help me solve my issue.

**Entity**

```
public class Video extends AbstractEntity {
@Column(name = "video_name")
private String videoName;

private boolean active;

@Column(name = "media_location")
private String mediaLocation;

@Column(name = "media_type")
private String mediaType;

@Column(name = "class_id")
private Integer classId;

@Column(name = "subject_id")
private Integer subjectId;
}
```

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping("/video")
public ResponseEntity<?> getByClassidAndSubjectId(@RequestParam("class id") Integer classId,
        @RequestParam("subject id") Integer subjectId) {
    return service.getByClassidAndSubjectId(classId,subjectId);

}
```

**Service**

```
public ResponseEntity<?> getByClassidAndSubjectId(Integer classId, Integer subjectId) {
    List<Video> videos = repository.getByClassIdAndSubjectId(classId, subjectId);

    if (videos.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>("no videos found by classId " + classId + " AND subjectId " + subjectId,
                HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    } else {
        List<Object> video = repository.findByClassIdAndSubjectId(classId,subjectId);
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(video, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Query(value = "SELECT id,video_name,media_location FROM video WHERE class_id=:classId AND subject_id=:subjectId", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object> findByClassIdAndSubjectId(@Param("classId")Integer classId,@Param("subjectId") Integer subjectId);
```

i am getting response like this
[
[
5,
"kannada",
"aws"
],
[
7,
"english",
"aws"
]
]

but i want response like

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "videoName": "xyz",
  "videopath": "xyz"
 },
 {
 "id": 2,
 "videoName": "abc",
 "videopath": "abc"
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

add json dependency your POM file  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20210307</version>
</dependency>
```

more details :- https://www.json.org/

Comment: Hi @Navishka  i added the dependency but still my problem not solved.
if u observe in service class i am using List<Object> instead of List<Video> why because in my video entity i have totally 6 fields but i want only 3 fields as response with key value pair  , if i use List<video> i am getting json format properly.
Any solution for this??

Comment: you can use a data transfer object (DTO) instead of an object  List<videoDTO>. and use model mapper to convert entity to dto easily